# En los EE.UU., ¿cuándo hay que usar "usted" y cuando hay que usar "tú"?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, formalidad, comparación-de-idiomas, estados-unidos, ustedeo

Vivo en los Estados Unidos. Aquí hay personas de todos los países hispanohablantes.

Si fuimos amigos muy familiares y muy cercanos emocionalmente en el pasado, ¿ya no debo hablar de *tú* porque solo los veo cada 5 años? ¿Depende de la edad de ellos?

Si veo a mi amigo de la iglesia con quien hablo en forma familiar en la iglesia, fuera de la iglesia en una situación casual, ¿le debo hablar de *tú*?

¿Hay una guía o un libro sobre este tema?

Si tengo sesenta y cinco años y mi amiga de toda mi vida tiene la misma edad, ¿le hablo en *tú*, o le hablo en *usted* por que somos ancianas ya?

Si estoy hablando un minuto con una persona de Centroamérica, luego con una persona de Argentina, y en otro momento con una persona chilena, ¿debo cambiar el uso de *usted* y *tú* dependiendo de la cultura de cada país?

Comment: ¡Bienvenida al sitio, Sra. Jackson! Realmente el uso de _usted_ y _tú_ es uno de los temas más complicados, incluso por parte de los propios hablantes.  Sin ir más lejos, yo ayer me debatía entre usar _tú_ y _usted_ con un señor algo mayor de una tienda, que no sé si me dijo alguna vez que lo tuteara, pero no pude recordarlo :D
A la mezcla de registros se le añade la edad de la gente. En tu caso, además, las opciones son mucho más grandes pues interactúas con gente de muchos países diferentes. Puedes leer más preguntas del tema mirando [tag:ustedeo].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es algo que varía no solo para cada país sino para cada región en un mismo país. Te pongo el ejemplo de Colombia. Para referirte a la segunda persona singular puedes usar "tú", "usted", "vos".

Podría clasificar el uso entre formal e informal:

- "Usted" es más usado en ámbitos profesionales y donde no hay previa confianza con el interlocutor.
- A medida que se desarrolla una relación o cercanía, se puede usar el "tú".
- "Vos" y "tú" también son usados de manera informal, entre amigos, conocidos y familia.

Sin embargo, una persona mayor en Bogotá podría percibir como falta de respeto que se le trate de "tú" o "vos". Así mismo, en otro lugar una persona podría percibir que eres cortante, antipático si lo tratas de "usted".

Mi opinión final (y lo que suelo hacer) es que uses "tú" en general y reserva "usted" para personas mayores (de 40 o 50 en adelante)

Comment: Gracias, Gustavo, por contestarme pronto.